# Grep 'hg incoming' result for specific files and save result - if there is files im looking for

Tags: django, bash, mercurial, grep

I want to create a script that will do something if `hg incoming -v` contains specific file.
Say `if hg incoming -v | grep models.py > 0` than do `./manage.py resetdb`. Something like this.
How can i set a flag (in bash script) based on `hg incoming -v | grep manage.py` result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if hg incoming -v | grep -q 'models\.py'; then
  ./manage.py resetdb
fi
```

However, this seems fragile: it matches when models.py is present in other output than files (such as description) and won't work when you modify models.py locally.  You can set a variable within the above to control later actions, if that's what you meant by "set a flag."

Comment: I know. But i didn't have any local modifications here. And i can live with wrong detection of keyword.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
count=`hg incoming -v | grep -c 'models\.py'`
if test $count -gt 0; then
   ./manage.py resetdb
fi
```

Comment: Use grep -c or --count instead if a count is desired.  It doesn't appear to be, however.

Comment: thanks Roger, I have never seen "-c" option before, very handy one

Comment: Thanks for backticks idea. Very handy.

Comment: @NilColor: `$()` has the same purpose yet nests better than backticks.  I don't have links handy but do see some general bash scripting guides.

Comment: @NilColor: check "The Unix Programming Environment" (http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Programming-Environment-Prentice-Hall-Software/dp/013937681X) for many other Unix practices